# How do I dynamically change the type hint of an inherited method?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Currently, I have a few database model classes that wrap database objects. I've created query classmethods for them and they each return an instance of themselves. Since the query process for each class is extremely similar, I want to put this method on the superclass. However, I can't seem to figure out how to dynamically type hint the return type for subclasses.

An abstraction of my current code:

```
class Base:
  ...

class Foo(Base):
  @classmethod
  def query(cls, **kwargs) -> 'Foo':
    foo_obj = cls(...) # interface with database
    return foo_obj

class Bar(Base):
  @classmethod
  def query(cls, **kwargs) -> 'Bar':
    bar_obj = cls(...) # interface with database
    return bar_obj
```

Ideally, I would instead want something like this:

```
class Base:
  @classmethod
  def query(cls, **kwargs) -> cls.__name__:
    obj = cls(...) # interface with database
    return obj

class Foo(Base):
  ...

class Bar(Base):
  ...
```

It does work without the type hint, but it would be far better if the type hint works.